# Android Package Installer

Tags: android, packageinstaller

Clicking on the apk file starts the android default installer activity with a cancel button and an install button. I would like to check that the user clicks on install button or on the cancel button. Please guide me thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check that whether that **package** is installed or not with the help of URI of app like *com.demo.example.pack* using this code i think this is the thing that you want :

```
 private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but to check if the package is installed or not i think it better to use broadcast reciever but what i want is to check the user clicks the install button or the cancel button on the package installer

Comment: if you don't know the package name of the app which you going to install then there is no functions available in android like you described.